# Создание локальной сети

Tags: передача-данных, сеть

Дайте пожалуйста несколько советов по настройке локальной сети в офисе, я в сетевых технологиях не очень разбираюсь.

Необходимо создать беспроводную локальную сеть в офисе с доступом в интернет и к сетевому принтеру.

Отдельно выделить гостевую сеть без доступа в локальную сеть компании

Из за того, что офис руководства, огражден толстой стеклянной витриной внутри практически не ловит wi-fi, на данный момент есть только роутер 1, уровень сигнала около 10-15%.

Нужно обойтись минимальными косметическими изменениями в офисе и если это возможно все сделать одним кабелем

Я создал примерную схему офиса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прочитал информацию в сети

1. На роутере 1 менять настройки не нужно, проверить Автоматическую раздачу DHCP. От LAN разъема роутера 1 нужно протянуть кабель в разъём WAN роутера 2
2. Роутер 2 выставить в режим сетевого моста и от его LAN разъема протянуть кабель в WAN разъем роутера 3.
3. От LAN разъёма роутера 3 протянуть кабель в сетевой принтер

Подскажите где я не прав и какие могут быть проблемы?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что все рабочие компьютеры офиса тоже должны быть подключены через беспроводную сеть? Переведя рабочую инфраструктуру на вайфай, вы огребёте проблемы с её функционированием. Рекомендую сразу сказать директору, что на таком уровне вы в сетях не разбираетесь, и отдать подрядчику. Учтите: сделать то, что он задумал, на нормальном уровне, стоит сравнимо с перепрокладкой кабельной сети и последующим косметическим ремонтом, а колхоз на роутерах домашнего класса икнётся неизбежно и неоднократно.

Comment: Не вижу надобности в третьем роутере. Или самые дальние от первого роутера клиенты тоже ни хрена не ловят? тогда я бы переместил первый роутер на угол аквариума.

Comment: @Akina, да вы правы, дальние клиенты тоже почти не ловят wi-fi. Переместить роутер не получиться, очень короткий кабель, который прокладывали сетевики, расстояние на схеме это максимально на сколько я смог его вытянуть и поставить там роутер нету возможности, он будет портить внешний вид в офисе

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev у подрядчика это выходит очень дорого, что протянуть по кабелю, что создать на беспроводной сети , поэтому директор поставил это ТЗ на меня.

Comment: Я и говорю. Сделать **это** так, чтобы оно **работало**, сто́ит дорого. Не совершайте ошибки, оставьте производственный процесс на кабеле.

Comment: *очень короткий кабель, который прокладывали сетевики* Делов-то - поставить I-коннектор да доложить ещё кусок кабеля до нужной точки...

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev в данный момент все работает через wi-fi на одном роутере ("Жизнь боль")

Comment: @Дмитрий Вы бы хоть указали модель роутера... потому как предложенная схема с независимым функционированием роутеров в принципе ущербная, при выпадении из зоны одного и попадании в зону другого будет идти реконнект, соответственно с лагом доступа во время переподключения. Надо использовать роутеры с бесшовным вайфаем и единым управлением, чтобы такой фигни не было - а это не все они умеют.

Comment: @Akina, этот вариант не подходит, не получиться никуда спрятать кабель, некуда ставить роутер около аквариума, там голая стеклянная витрина, отсутствует кабелегон и плинтус, закрепить кабель никак не получиться и он будет висеть или лежать на полу, что недопустимо
Пускай будет шовное соединение, аля Руководство, Гости, Рабочая группа. Роутер 1 tp-link n300(от провайдера), на 2 и 3 планирую приобрести Ubiquiti AirRouter HP

Comment: Если нагрузки на сеть серьезные, ВайФай не подойдёт. Серьезность нагрузок определяется объемом документа оборота внутри сети + зашаренные ресурсы. Так никто не делает. Подключайте клиентов только проводами, и создавайте ВайФай для гостевой сети. Во время ланча с СВЧ печкой у сотрудников, с сетью на ВайФай бывают траблы :)

Comment: @Дмитрий *этот вариант не подходит [skipped] Пускай будет шовное соединение* Ну Вы тёплое-то с мягким не путайте, да... нет места для кабеля - ну и пусть его нет, будет три точки, а не две, чхать. А бесшовка-то всё одно лучше. Просто роутеры (все три, а не дополнительно два) закупить не абы какие, а чтобы и гостевую сеть умели, и в команде работать, да настроить нормально.

Comment: @Akina, приобрел два микротика, попробую настроить:)
Ребят, всем спасибо за советы и помощь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, лично я б сделал так (нищебродски-энтерпрайзный вариант)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## СКС

- Витуху бросил бы в плинтус. Для каждого раб. места - 4 пары (2 для 100мб. сети и 2 для IP-телефона) в случае с розеткой. Но можно, например, из IP-телефона (например yealink t23g) сделать коммутатор и тогда на раб. место понадобится всего 2 пары.
- Коммутатор №1 и маршрутизатор установил бы в монтажный шкаф в "аквариуме" боссов который повешал бы под потолок - смотрится он не плохо, достаточно в стене всего 2 (лучше 4) дырки под крепления + кабель канал для него. Впрочем, ничего не изменится от его переноса кроме длинны витой пары. Если у них кабинет из красного дерева, то, наверно, лучше поместить в другом месте.
- От коммутатора №2 растащил бы так же витуху в плинтусе до прочих раб. станций на правой стороне. Принтер и "аквариум" боссов таким же методом к коммутатору №1.
- Точки доступа можно повешать на фальш потолок, а можно на стены, крепятся одним шурупом, смотрятся красиво.
- Раздачу wifi в "аквариуме" боссов можно возложить на роутер. В этом случае лучше приобрести двухдиапазонный (тот что в моём примере работает только на 2.4GHz) либо поставить ещё одну точку доступа если этого будет не хватать.

## Сеть

!**ДИСКЛЕЙМЕР**! Если вы не имеете подобного опыта, то лучше заручиться помощью специалистов.

- Все соединения между сетевым оборудованием совершать двумя линками в агрегированном канале (разумеется, это должны поддерживать коммутаторы).
- В сети на L2 уровне разместил бы 3 вилана: vl100 - управление; vl200 - служебный доступ; vl300 - гостевой доступ.
- Терминатором виланов выступает разумеется роутер. На точки доступа приходят виланы: vl100 для управления; Для vl200 мы раздаём серую сеть и NAT'им её на маршрутизаторе, таким образом гарантируем доступ и к лок. ресурсам и в интернет; vl300 шейпим роутером в 5Mbit (достаточно для гостей) на сессию, точно так же NAT'им в интернет. Кол-во сессий ограничиваем.
- На рабочие станции (включая принт-сервер) подаётся только vl200 по витой паре, либо по wifi в служебной сети.
- Использовал бы 2 аплинка (провайдера) для обеспечения отказоустойчивости. Возможно второй провайдер - 4G/LTE
- (опционально) В случае, если обязательно нужна хорошая IP-телефония - создать отдельный вилан для IP-телефонов. Так будет в будущем проще определять политики QoS маршрутизатора.
- (опционально) Приобрёл бы самый дешёвый nettop/orange pi для Unifi controller и установил бы в коммутационный шкаф. Очень полезная штука для управления/диагностики точек доступа, strongly recommended для организации бесшовного роуминга (подробные howto в огромном кол-ве можно найти на ubnt.su).
- (опционально) Маршрутизировал бы vl200 и vl300 в разные белые адреса, в идеале - в разные провайдеры.

## Оборудование

- Роутер начиная от mikrotik RB2011 (По наблюдениям не плохо справляется с ~20 клиентами)
- Точки доступа начиная от Ubiquiti UniFi AC Lite AP (Вообще можно любые двухдиапазонные)
- Коммутаторы начиная от: Любые управляемые (d-link/tp-link т.к. для энтерпрайз сегмента низкие цены)
- Шкаф коммутационный для роутера и коммутатора: https://shop.nag.ru/catalog/14021.Nastennye-shkafy/14031.4U/27237.SNR-BTS3004
- Не помешало бы установить ИБП, хотя бы в шкаф.